# SQL Service Broker example not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, service-broker

I have two databases on the same instance.

One called ICMS, one called CarePay_DEV1

When a change happens in ICMS (Source), it needs to send a message to CarePay_Dev1 (Destination).

I am new to Broker Services, and am trying to make a message go to the queue. Once that works, I will hopefully get the data into a table in the destination, and that will then be processed by .Net code.  But I just want something to appear in the destination first.

So, step 1: I enable the service on the two databases

```
-- Enable Broker on CarePay
ALTER DATABASE CarePay_Dev1
SET ENABLE_BROKER; 

-- Enable Broker on Source
ALTER DATABASE ICMS_TRN
SET ENABLE_BROKER;
```

Step 2: Create the message type on the source and destination.

```
-- Create Message Type on Receiver:
USE CarePay_DEV1
GO
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [IcmsCarePayMessage]
VALIDATION=WELL_FORMED_XML;

-- Create Message Type on Sender:
USE ICMS_TRN
GO
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [IcmsCarePayMessage]
VALIDATION=WELL_FORMED_XML;
```

I then create the Contacts, on both databases:

```
-- Create Message Type on Receiver:
USE CarePay_DEV1
GO
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [IcmsCarePayMessage]
VALIDATION=WELL_FORMED_XML;

-- Create Message Type on Sender:
USE ICMS_TRN
GO
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [IcmsCarePayMessage]
VALIDATION=WELL_FORMED_XML;
```

I then create the message queues on both databases:

```
-- CREATE Sending Messagw Queue
USE ICMS_TRN
GO
CREATE QUEUE CarePayQueue


-- CREATE Receiving Messagw Queue
USE CarePay_Dev1
GO
CREATE QUEUE CarePayQueue
```

And finally, I create the services on both databases:

```
-- Create the message services
USE ICMS_TRN
GO
CREATE SERVICE [CarePayService]
ON QUEUE CarePayQueue


USE CarePay_DEV1
GO
CREATE SERVICE [CarePayService]
ON QUEUE CarePayQueue
```

Now, the queues should be ready, so then I try and send something from the source to the destination:

```
-- SEND THE MESSAGE!
USE ICMS_TRN
GO

DECLARE @InitDlgHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @RequestMessage VARCHAR(1000) 

BEGIN TRAN

    BEGIN DIALOG @InitDlgHandle
    FROM SERVICE [CarePayService]
    TO SERVICE 'CarePayService'
    ON CONTRACT [IcmsCarePayContract]

    SELECT @RequestMessage = N'<Message>The eagle has landed!</Message>';

    SEND ON CONVERSATION @InitDlgHandle
    MESSAGE TYPE [IcmsCarePayMessage] (@RequestMessage)

COMMIT TRAN
```

I get:

> Command(s) completed successfully.

But then when I try select from the destination queue, it's empty.

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 *, casted_message_body = 
CASE message_type_name WHEN 'X' 
  THEN CAST(message_body AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
  ELSE message_body 
END 
FROM [CarePay_DEV1].[dbo].[CarePayQueue] WITH(NOLOCK)
```

Can anyone spot the issue? I can't see where I tell the destination which database to send the message to - which could be part of the issue?

Comment: you need to use security certificates in order to send messages from one database to another - look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_service_broker/archive/2008/08/26/securing-a-dialog-with-certificates.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend you read Adam Machanic's [Service Broker Advanced Basics Workbench](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/service-broker-advanced-basics-workbench/), specifically the section entitled "Routing and Cross-Database Messaging".

In addition, for future troubleshooting you may want to use [SSBDiagnose](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934450.aspx) or also read through [Remus Rusanu's numerous articles](http://rusanu.com/articles/) on the topic

Answer (score 1):

I think the initiator service sent a message to yourself. Try to change the name of destination (terget) service.

Comment: Thanks. Renamed all Services/contracts/queues on source database to have a 'tx' in the name, and all the services/contracts/queues on the destination to have Rx. Still, nothing seem to appear in either queue.

Comment: what's in (SELECT * FROM sys.transmission_queue) for initiator db?

Comment: Ah, there are rows in there! to_service_name = CarePayRxService, to_broker_instance is blnak, from_service_name = CarePayTxService, Service_contract_name = IcmsCarePayTxContract, message_type_name = IcmsCarePayMessage and transmission_status = blank. The blanks are worrying?

Comment: No, it's normal, because you do not use a PATH with broker instance. Make sure that the receiving queue is enabled. (ALTER QUEUE [youTargetQueue] WITH status = ON;)

Comment: That didn't make a difference. What confuses me is that there seem to be no connection between my source and destination database. No where do I say which database the messages should go to. Am I not missing something?

Comment: Both bases have by default ROUTE [AutoCreatedLocal]  WITH  ADDRESS  = N'LOCAL'. This should work.